# eigenvector problem encountered in markov chain / random walk with drift

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Is there a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where
$$
pf_{1-n} + (1-p)f_{n-1} = f_{n}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? $p$ is some real number $0 < p < 1$.

Comment: Try $f_n=c$ for all $n$, for any constant $c$.

Comment: ahh good catch! are there any other solutions? how about one with finite $f_0$ and $\sum_n f_n = 1$?

Comment: Are you sure about the $f_{1-n}$? Seems like it should be $f_{n+1}$.

Comment: strange looking I know but it represents the physical situation where a particle's velocity over a given time interval either increases by one unit (with probability 1-p) or increases by one and then scatters, which reverses its velocity